# Winston for logging a mulitlpe container application

Tags: node.js, logging, digital-ocean, winston

I am planning to use the Digital Ocean App Platform to host my backend but I wanted to know if each container in App platform would have a different log file (assuming I’m logging into files with Winston) and if this is the case would this even be an issue.

I thought of multiple solutions in case I should handle this:

1- Log into the database

2- Make another container that expects to get the logs through HTTP from the other running containers.

(**Note** I'm new with dealing with containers so I might be missing/misunderstanding something)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get log files from each node.js process. For this scenario Winston supports alternative [transports](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md) that can centralize logs from many sources.

As you suggested (2) [some of these transport options](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#postgresql-transport) write logs to an RDBMS.